# How to restart the SSR script in Vite?

Tags: node.js, vite

I am using the [Dev server](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-javascript.html#vitedevserver) provided by Vite. It provides a method to run the SSR code using the `ssrLoadModule` method on the dev server instance. This how I use it:

```js
const vite = await createServer({
  mode: 'development',
  appType: 'custom',
  root: path.join(process.cwd(), 'server'),
  build: {
    ssr: 'server/main.ts'
  },
  server: {
    hmr: true
  },
  ssr: {
    format: 'cjs',
    target: 'node'
  },
  plugins: []
});

const loadedModule = await vite.ssrLoadModule('server/main.ts');
```

Here the above file runs the `server/main.ts` file and also imports another file `user.ts`. The `main.ts` file creates an Express app/server that listens on port `3000` which exposes CRUD APIs for `User` entity.

My question is how do I restart after the SSR script (main.ts) or any of its import dependencies get modified? I don't care if it is a full restart or HMR. *Note, the HMR works for frontend code but not for backend SSR code.*